# Getting product attributes in event checkout_cart_product_add_after

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have observer for Magento event checkout_cart_product_add_after. Now I need to check if for example t-shirt size is same what user had given to Magento in my custom module. How can I get those product attributes in my observer?

```
class Company_ModuleSizes_Model_Sizes_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    public function check_sizes($observer)
    {       
        // Get quote item
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quoteItem = $event->getQuoteItem();

        // How can I get product attributes from $quoteItem  ?

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can request the sales/quote_item object instance directly from the observer i.e. `$quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();`

Comment: Also, your event observer shouldn't/does not need to extend `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$_options = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getData('your-attribute');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Company_ModuleSizes_Model_Sizes_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function check_sizes($observer)
    {       
        // Get Quote Item
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quoteItem = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $event->getProduct();

        // The options provided by the customer is available using the following statement
        $_optionsQuoteItem = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getData('your-attribute');

        // The options which are available for the product in general is available using the following statement
        $_optionsProduct = $product->getData('your-attribute');

        // Now you can process your required logic in here, with the above two variables

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `$product->getData('your-attribute');` will not return a list of options. It will always return `null` for chosen configurable product options in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to get the product attributes in the `Observer.php`. Hope this helps someone

```
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('selling_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```